# Problema com SFML no Code Blocks Windows 32 bits

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, sfml

Eu instalei o SFML no CodeBlocks usando as instruções daqui

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php

Então eu compilei o código exemplo de lá, que deveria exibir uma janela com um circulo verde:

```css
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A janela esperada aparece, porém sem o circulo verde e ela é transparente. O que está errado?

Comment: Prado, bem vindo ao SOpt, acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour. Evite usar links nas perguntas, se usar, use como "referência". Você pode editá-la e colocar parte do código e explicar melhor seu problema. Círculo verde? Se for o caso dá para colar figuras ou imagens, um "PrintScreen", por exemplo.